# How can I speed up the slides in my CSS vertical slider?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I need a slider which would move slides in a vertical direction. The issue with my code is that transition between slides are too slow. Each slide should stay at least 5 sec and transition between next slide should be very quick like we see at the slick slider and so.

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slideshow li {
  left: 0px;
  height:20px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 17s infinite;
}


#slideshow li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6.25s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#slideshow li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 11.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="slideshow">
  <li>slide1</li>
  <li>slide2</li>
  <li>slide3</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljhdeb0c/4/)

Comment: I think you'd need to change the percentages to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the values of

```
#slideshow li {
  left: 0px;
  height:20px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 3s infinite; /*adjust here*/
}



#slideshow li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.25s; /*Adjust here*/
  opacity: 0;
}

#slideshow li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;/*Adjust here*/
  opacity: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljhdeb0c/6/

Answer (score 0):

By changing percentage of animation keyframe I have done it. This is what I was looking for.

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slideshow li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height:20px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 10s infinite;
}


#slideshow li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  opacity: 0;
}


@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  5%, 50%{
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  51.1%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="slideshow">
  <li>slide1</li>
  <li>slide2</li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljhdeb0c/7/)